# A border of my TextBox is missing in this xaml

Tags: c#, uwp

Not sure if its a bug or a mistake. The right edge of a TextBox is missing in this piece of code.

The Code:

```
<Page
    x:Class="NickyStudio.UI.BlankPage1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:NickyStudio.UI"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:Height="40"
    d:Width="500"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" Spacing="2">
        <TextBlock Text="Export Scale" Width="100" Padding="8,6"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="exportScale" Text="hello" 
             Width="50" Padding="3,4" TextAlignment="Center" />
        <Grid Width="10" />
        <TextBlock Text="%" Padding="10,6"/>
        <Grid Width="40" />
        <Button Content="50" Tapped="SetExportScale" Tag="50" Margin="5,0"></Button>
        <Button Content="100" Tapped="SetExportScale" Tag="100" Margin="5,0"></Button>
        <Button Content="200" Tapped="SetExportScale" Tag="200" Margin="5,0"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Page>
```

Here is how it render in editor and in execution:

[image]

Comment: I don't know why it happens but wouldn't setting the Margin in the TextBlock instead of using grids solve the problem? `<TextBlock Text="%" Padding="10,6" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>`

Comment: Nope. It won't solve the problem.

Comment: Do you see the same issue if you paste the above XAML markup into a new blank `Page`? I doubt it. Please post the full element tree required to reproduce your issue. The problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Updated the code to a full xaml page. The issue still exist.

Comment: You could to set the width a little bit bigger like 100. Then please change the Style of the TextBox to remove the built-in delete button.

Comment: @Nick: What's the size of the parent window/screen? Can't reproduce this on my machine. But you need to increase the size of the `StackPanel`, one way or another.

Comment: @mm8 I already specified d:Height="40" d:Width="500" to the page tag. It should be the same size in your VS visual designer.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT If I changed the width from 50 to 70 (or large) the border became visible. Looks like its a bug.

Comment: @Nick: So it's a designer issue? There are many of them. How does it look at runtime?

Comment: @mm8 It actually not only happens in designer but also in runtime.

Comment: It's an interesting question. I'll consult the team to check this behavior

Answer (score 0):

After talking with the team, we found this issue has been reported in WinUI early. And our team had fixed this bug that textbox clipping under small width and height. Currently, we'd suggest you use the TextBox control from the WinUI library (v2.3.191007001 or higher):`Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.TextBox` to avoid this behavior.